# SSRS Remove whitespace from hidden footer or How to stick a text a the bottom of the last page only

Tags: reporting-services, footer, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using Report Builder 3.0. I'm not using tables or lists. I am using expressions in a textbox. Values show up fine and even expand to new pages which is what I want. Now my problem is I have another textbox that has to be positioned at the bottom of the last page no matter how many pages the report ends up with. This textbox cant just be after the first one, it has to be at the bottom of the last page (as a report footer). I can't use a page footer as it will leave blank space in the previous pages which is not what the business wants.
Any ideas on how to make this happen? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This is actually harder than it sounds or should be. The only way I can think of would be to calculate the distance between the last record and the bottom of the page. This would have to be based on the number of records displayed and how many records you have per page. Then to apply this, you could add line returns to the beginning of your textbox to push the text down.

In case you need it, line returns are called `vbCrLf` in expressions. Make sure the `Can Grow` property is on for your textbox.

Comment: I think that's the only way too. Now do you know to retrieve that distance?

Comment: @Pasoum This is my idea on how to make this happen. Hopefully it points you in the right direction. If you run into specific issues once you've made an attempt at this approach, I would suggest posting that as a new question with as many details as possible.

Comment: Ok @StevenWhite. I tried that already and I can't figure out how to retrieve the overall size of the page, the size of my textbox and calculate the rest of the report size.

Comment: In the View menu, make sure Properties is turned on. Click on the blue background around the report to see the Report Properties. The size of items are in their properties. You will definitely have to play around with it, but figure out how many lines you have per page to start with.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the text box as the "last" thing in the body of the report, it will only print on the last page. It can only print after every other object has printed and (if they were tablixes) cycled through the dataset. To hide the footer, just right click in the Footer, choose properties, and uncheck "Print on Last Page".

Comment: @Ritcey Thanks for your reply. I tried this, it prints my textbox at the last page only but still not at the very bottom of the report.

Comment: The textbox will print relative to the items above it, not an absolute position unless you are in control of how high everything above it is with precision. Is there a reason you cannot put this box on the last page in the footer?

Comment: The reason is in my question and it is because a footer area will still be preserved in previous pages even though the footer is hidden in those pages. Say I have 4inces reserved for the footer, that means I will have a blank space of 4inches in every page of my report which is not what the client wants.

Comment: > Is there a reason you cannot put this box on the last page in the footer?